# Ajax post with on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('body').on('click','.removebet i',function(e){
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    var data = "a="+a;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yorumcikar.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(e){
    });
```

I'll explain the problem. I can post AJAX form with this function and there's no problem except the `.removebet i` comes from the ajax.

If I append `.removebet i` with AJAX this function doesn't work because it doesn't call AJAX.

example:

```
$(".maindiv").html("<span class='removebet'><i>Yes</i></span>");
```

Then when I clicked to 'i' tag the function at top doesn't work.

Comment: Could you try explaining your problem a little more. It doesn't make much sense at the moment. Also, I assume the syntax errors are just copy + paste mistakes?

Comment: Your last sentence seems to be saying that your `.removebet i` element isn't created until after it's clicked, which obviously can't be what you really mean. Is there some other code, not shown, that creates the `.removebet i` element?

Comment: Do you really have `<i>` tags under elements with class `removebet` on your page?

Comment: NITPICK: Why are you using an <i> as a clickable element? Use a clickable element!

Comment: You're delegating the click event. The event you're interested in is when a `.removebet i` element is clicked, OK... with you so far. These elements are inserted using AJAx calls... again: nothing wrong with that. These elements are being added after the click event callback calls the AJAX function... OK, so ajax is called to add an element, that has to be clicked for an ajax call to take place so that ajax call can add the element that calls ajax to add... see the problem?

Comment: I'll try to tell.
For example I've a div as '.maindiv' and I'm posting some datas into this div with ajax just like $(".maindiv").html('<span class="removebet"><i>Yes</i></span>').Then when I click "i" tag my function doesnt work

Comment: Your code works...http://jsfiddle.net/kVEwy/ There is something else that is wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DJ3eM/

Comment: @epascarello, the problem is with AJAX. when I use 'on' I cant make ANY AJAX POST

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the click event to your success handler?

Comment: What is `data`? Add an `error` callback! It is not always going to be successful. You better account for that so your users are not sitting in the dark.

Comment: i've read here wrongly actually data is : var data = "a="+a;

Comment: Are you trying to construct query string like NVPs by doing `'a='+a`? You can pass a plain object like `{a:a}` to `$.post`.

Comment: problem is not about data bro. because, i'm living problem with only "ajax posted tags" i cant click them. only ajax posted tags have problems. the others don't.

Comment: Problem is you got that part right theoretically, so people will have to look elsewhere. Good luck with that.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this should work.

```
$('.removebet > i').click(function(event){
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(a);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yorumcikar.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(retval){
            alert(retval);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT

This will work, however each newly added item will not be bound as the binding has already happened.  In order to get newly added items to be bound as well you will have to rebind them when they are added.

```
$.ajax({call to get your new item},
      success: function(data){
          // add to dom
          bindElement(newElement);
      }
 });

function bindElement(element){
$(element).click(function(event){
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(a);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yorumcikar.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(retval){
            alert(retval);
        }
    });
});
}
```

Comment: This will explicitly not work, since the ajax will add new `.removebet i` matching elements which will not be bound by this. He is already properly delegating his event, this however is incorrect.

Comment: this is not what i'm searching for. i'm searching for a function that works with ajax posts

Comment: This question was changed while i was answering it.  Sorry for the confusion. originally he had asked why it was not working to call the ajax unless he removed the '.removebet i' from the on call

Comment: Delegation will still be a better approach for handling this, though.